# Only replace x if there is a number behind it

Tags: python, regex

I have this program in python that solves a equation but it can only use "3*x" not "3x". So i want the regex to only replace "x" with "*x" if there is a number in front of it.

have thought about using the re.sub() but don't know what the regex should be if it should only replace the x if there is a number in front.

So i would like to have "2x + 8 = 3x + x" to become "2*x + 8 = 3*x + x"

Thanks in advice :)

Comment: Does `(?<=\d)x` work?

Comment: Yes. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that you might want to design an expression maybe similar to:

```
import re

regex = r"(?<=\d)([xyz])"
test_str = ("2x + 8 = 3x + x\n"
    "2x + 8y = 3z + x")

subst = "*\\1"

print(re.sub(regex, subst, test_str))
```

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/ojVxVF/1/) if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it.